# Get Random Folder name and write it as %FolderName%

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have:

"C:\DIR\FOLDER-NAME_Random-String"

and need a script that will check this random name of folder and write it as %FolderName%.

I have many computers with C:\DIR\Folder-Name_Random-String [eg. C:\Dir\Photo_2015-05, C:\Dir\Photo_2009_11, C:\Dir\Photo_2001_01, etc...].
If that folder exist script must get folder name [example: Photo_2015-05] and set as environment variable.

Something like this:

"

C:\

Cd DIR

dir

if exist photo*.* get name photo...

SET %FolderName%=Photo_random-string

"

Please help! :-)

Comment: most won't understand you. I think you want to take that string `"C:\DIR\FOLDER-NAME_Random-String"`  and set an environment variable  to equal Random-String  which is what follows the last _  until the end of the string.

Comment: this may help part of the way `echo "c:\blah\folder-name_random-string" | grep -Po "(?<=_).*$"`  and this `for /f %f in ('echo asdf') do set a=%f`  You  / somebody has just gotta somehow find out how to combine the two!

Answer (score 0):

Considering only one folder will exist at any given time.

```
for /d %a in (Photo*) do (>nul 2>nul dir /a-d "%a\*.txt" && (set FOLDERNAME=%a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this 
This is working ver:

```
C:
CD\
CD DIR
IF EXIST FOTO_* (CD FOTO_*) ELSE (goto END)
FOR %%I IN (.) DO SET FOLDERNAME=%%~nI%%~xI
CD\
ECHO %FOLDERNAME% Exist - Delete it !
RD /q %FOLDERNAME%
PAUSE
END
Exit
```

Maybe someone use this in feature ;)

Regards